# Newton's Iteration Method in 32-bit Assembly using Irvine32 Library

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to write a program that approximates the root of a user-inputted value using Newton's Iteration method. I found this website that does it in a way that wouldn't require the use of derivatives (https://hackernoon.com/calculating-the-square-root-of-a-number-using-the-newton-raphson-method-a-how-to-guide-yr4e32zo).

I'm having trouble with writing a square root sub-routine that I would then call in another function that would solve a quadratic equation. If anyone has any insights, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: x86 has sqrt in hardware (via the FPU); using that will be faster than manual Newton iterations on modern CPUs, even if you use x87 `fsqrt` with 80-bit precision (64-bit mantissa) instead of SSE2 `sqrtsd`.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. Thank you for your response, as always!

Comment: @PeterCordes Since fsqrt stores the result in st(0), how can I move that value from the stack to a variable or even a register so that I can use it for more calculations?

Comment: `st(0)` is a register, where you need it for more FP computation.  If you want to convert it to 32 or 64-bit integer, you can use `fistp dword [esp]` to round to nearest (and integer reload if you want).  If you just want to store it as a `double`, `fstp qword [esp]` or whatever.  Read any tutorial on x87 e.g. http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html, or look at compiler output, like `gcc -mno-sse` on https://godbolt.org/